# href link and dropdown btn-group div are not aligned properly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

The Editing Link and button group are not aligned properly. button group is slightly below when matched with the editing link button. I want them both aligned.
I want to do this without using any CSS.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
  <a href="/cs/roger/index.php?type=editing" class="btn btn-warning">Editing</a>

  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle
glyphicon glyphicon-list" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
      <li><a href="/cs/roger/index.php?type=open" >Open</a></li>
      <li><a href="/cs/roger/index.php?type=approved" >Approved</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the Fiddle: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/11850/)
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the glyphicon to an other `span` inside the `button`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
    <a href="/cs/roger/index.php?type=editing" class="btn btn-warning">Editing</a>
    
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" title="Project Status">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list "></span>
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="/cs/roger/index.php?type=open" >Open</a></li>
            <li><a href="/cs/roger/index.php?type=approved" title="Lists all approved projects">Approved</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

In your example you are adding the glyphicon classes to the `button` itself.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle glyphicon glyphicon-list" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" title="Project Status">
  <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```

Which will lead to the slightly wrong formatting. Just give the glyphicon it's own `span` inside the `button`.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" title="Project Status">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list "></span>
    <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the mistake. :)